# Form tags distorting the div alignment in internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two divs in separate form tags. They render correctly in chrome and firefox but unfortunately not in IE. The alignment of the divs get distorted. If it remove the first form tag from the code it solves the alignment issue but I am not able to postback in the link in the second form tag.Hence I need to separate both the divs in two different form tags. Can somebody help

```
<form>
    <div id="FundsNetworkNotAvailable" class="msgError" runat="server">
                <%--These date is dynamically pulled from the config file--%>
                <h2>Attention</h2>
                <p>
                    FundsNetwork will be carrying out maintenance work on their website over the weekend from 
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FundsNetworkNotAvailableFrom" Text="19/12/2009" />
                    to 
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FundsNetworkNotAvailableUntil" Text="20/12/2009" />. 
                During this period, their website will become unavailable. 
                We apologise for the disruption and any inconvenience caused.
                </p>
            </div>
            <br />
        </form>

</form>

<form id="post_info_to_Fidelity" name="post_info_to_Fidelity" method="post" target="_blank" action="https://www.fidelity.co.uk/investor/site/general/jsp/general_set_cookie.jsp">


            <input name="page" value="isaPlusAO" type="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="WLSEDOLS" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="WLSEDOLS_INSIDE_ISA_VALUES" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="WLSEDOLS_OUTSIDE_ISA_VALUES" value="">
            <input name="oafRate" value="0.45" type="hidden">
            <input name="vatable" value="false" type="hidden">
            <input name="Advicegiven" value="no" type="hidden">
            <input name="partner" value="best" type="hidden">
            <input name="Context" value="isaPlusAO" type="hidden">
            <input name="IGNORE_RemoveUserFromSession" value="yes" type="hidden">
            <input name="isNewClient" value="true" type="hidden">
            <input name="AdviserClient" value="1" type="hidden">
            <input name="AgentCode" value="170224" type="hidden">
            <input name="returnURL" value="http://select.bestinvest.co.uk" type="hidden">
            <input name="Title" value="" type="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="Surname" size="25" maxlength="25" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="FirstNames" size="25" maxlength="25" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="HouseName" size="25" maxlength="25" value="">

            <div class="ColSplit Third inset insetThird" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #E1E1E1;">
                <h2 class="NoBorder">Select an investment option with FundsNetwork</h2>
                <p>
                    To transact through FundsNetwork you will firstly need to login to your

                    <a href="https://www.fidelity.co.uk/investor/site/general/jsp/general_set_cookie.jsp"
                        title="Link to FundsNetwork account manager. (opens in a new window)" 
                        target="_blank">FundsNetwork Account Manager </a>.


                    To access this you will need your 
                    FundsNetwork Customer Reference Number (a ten digit number beginning with ‘1’ 
                    that can found on your most recent statement from FundsNetwork) and pin. Please
                    call FundsNetwork on 0800 995511 if you need help logging in to the account manager.
                </p>
                <div class="cta fRight">

                    <input title="Link to FundsNetwork account manager. (opens in a new window)" type=submit value=Go class="button">





                </div>
            </div>


        </form>
```

Comment: apply CSS rules on both forms( using floats or put them in separate divs  ). It will not allow browsers to use their default rendering

Comment: Try putting both of them in separate Divs containers

Comment: i put both the form tags in div containers and set the div style to  <div style = "float:left;"> but there seems to be no affect

Comment: <div style = "float:left;">
            <form>
            </form>
         </div> 
 <div style = "float:left;">
            <form>
            </form>
         </div>

Comment: Have to add clear <div style = "float:left;>form</div> <div style = "float:left;> form2</div>  
<div style = "clear:both"></div>

Comment: tried this with no effect. <div style = "float:left;">
            <form>
            </form>
         </div> 
 <div style = "float:left;">
            <form>
            </form>
         </div>      
  <div style = "clear:both"></div>

Comment: Need to know, how do u want to align these forms.
Horizontly or vertically?

Comment: vertical. The second div is closer to the left margin compared to the first div